# Ubuntu server detecting electricity outage?

Tags: networking, server, power-management, shutdown, ups

I am in the planning stage for setting up my server and have some doubts.
Firstly my network is something like this:
One parent PC connected to the internet and 3 other child PCs which are not connected to the internet but connected to the parent PC by LAN. The parent PC has its own UPS while the 3 child PCs share another UPS (so in all there are 2 UPS only).

My concern is that in case of power outage I want the parent PC to remain on using the UPS, but I want the child PCs to shutdown immediately. When the electricity is back I want the 3 child PCs to turn on again. How do I control the child PCs from the parent PC using automated software?

All the PCs will be running Ubuntu server.
This is the only server that I have.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this seems to be a very interesting project. As far as I know most modern UPS have a USB connection to provide a shutdown signal to the connected computer. You could analyze the signal your UPS might provide you. To control the three child server you could send a shutdown command via ssh (pub key authentication) upon power loss.

Maybe there is another plug-and-play device that could monitor your power plugs voltage and send it's data to the parent server if the first option is not working.

If there is no such device listed above and your UPS don't provide a signal cable, the only way I see is "hacking" the UPS itself and grab some electrical signal that could trigger a Raspberry Pi port which shuts down your machines via ssh.

**But be carefull because you are dealing with high voltages and high currents that can do lethal harm if they are not treated with extreme caution.**

To boot up the machines again you should look into your BIOS. Most modern Motherboards have the `WakeOnLan` function which powers the computer up if a correspinding signal is recieved via LAN.

Comment: Another question, is this for home use or business use?

Comment: For business use. I am developing a software which I want to provide as a service using my own server.

Comment: okay, for now I have no more ideas than above. Did you consider the chance of a long electricity outage? Does it happen often at your office(?). Is it really needed to fully shutdown the servers? How long would the UPS last on full server load? Is there a professional solution as you would use it for business?

Comment: In my locality there are frequent electricity outages. I dont want to frequently visit the server location to lookup if there was an electricity outage and to start the PCs when the electricity is back. The objective is to automate these operations so that I dont have to go to the server more than once a month.

Comment: I have no experience in networking or even setting up a server. So please let me know if my requirement is far-fetched. I am not aware of any professional solution to this problem.

Comment: I won't say this is impossible or far-fetched but if you are new to server's and electrical engineering the best and easiest solution would be hosting your server at a major web hosting company. This will also guaratee you no power outages, 24/7 uptime and great upload speed. So you could concentrate on developing than on keeping your servers running. If possible I would recommend you to get in touch with a experienced server administrator to get your server up and running **securely** (!).

Comment: I am a little bit interested now, what kind of software are you developing (if I may ask)?

Comment: Its a HPC software for engineering activities. Cant disclose more as the product itself is the USP (Unique Selling Point).
As per my calculations, I can economically run my business only if I use my own server. If I use some other server service like AWS or Azure then I will have to charge extravagantly to my customers. This is again because it is HPC and the non-sense pricing policy of these vendors is not helping me anywhere.